# Angular filter to strip away all characters up to and including the first space in a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an angular expression in my html which returns some data:

```
  <span>
        {{thing.data | stripFirstName}}
  </span>
```

Returns:

```
Phillip Smith
```

Using a filter, I want to always strip away the first name. So I want to remove all characters up to and including the first space.

Somthing like this perhaps?

```
    .filter("stripFirstName", function() {
    return function(x) {
        SOMTHING
        return x.substring();
    };
});
```

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filter("stripFirstName", function() {
    return function(x) {
        return x.substr(x.indexOf(' ')+1);
    };
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.filter('stripFirstName', function() {
    return function(x) {
        return x.split(/\s+/)[1];
    };
}
```